# Make empty copy of dictionary of same type in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

In my class var section, I have something like:

```
class Foobar {
    var things:[String:Thing] = [:]
    ...
}
```

Later on, I might have a function that wants to create a dictionary of the same types. But it's not directly derived from the original, so I can't use some of the builtin functions to just make it directly. So I end up repeating myself

```
var newThings[String:Thing] = [:]
```

Is there some syntax/way that I can do something like

```
var newThing = self.things.emptyCopy()
```

Such that I wouldn't have to repeat the types, it would just be the same type annotation as the original variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dynamicType` to get the type of the variable,
and use that to create a new (empty) instance of the same type with the `init()` constructor:

```
var things : [String : Int] = [ "foo" : 1, "bar" : 2]

var newThings = things.dynamicType() // Type is [String : Int]
println(newThings) // [:]

newThings["baz"] = 3
println(newThings) // [baz: 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some syntax/way that I can do something like
>
> ```
> var newThing = self.things.emptyCopy()
> ```

Like this:

```
var newThing = self.things
newThing.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Such that I wouldn't have to repeat the types

Maybe with `typealias` depending on your real-life needs?

```
typealias MyDict = [String:Int]

class Foobar {
    var things:MyDict = [:]
}

var newThings:MyDict = [:]
```

An upside of this solution is that you make explicit *why* these two variables should be of the same type by choosing a good name for your alias.